# How to order a Dictionary based on the value?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a Dictionary  like

```
tel = {'jack': 18, 'sape': 4139, 'sar': 2139, 'mape': 319, 'sipe': 29}
```

I want to order it based on the value in descending order like

```
tel = {'sape': 4139, 'sar': 2139, 'mape': 319, 'sipe': 29 'jack': 18}
```

I searched the web a lot and found unrelated results. Is there any built-in function there or else any other way?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to order a `dict`. Either use an ordered dictionary, or some other ordered sequence.

```
sorted(tel.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.7 or 3.1, you can use OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
tel = {'jack': 18, 'sape': 4139, 'sar': 2139, 'mape': 319, 'sipe': 29}
newtel = OrderedDict(sorted(tel.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

More examples can be found in the [What's New](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.1.html#pep-372-ordered-dictionaries) doc.

EDIT: Now using itemgetter instead of lambda, to please those who care.  Apologies to those who found it more clear the old way.

Comment: Its more pythonic to use `operator.itemgetter` rather than a lambda for the sort key.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

and that can be [usefull](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/).